# Change price by another value RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm beginner in RoR. Just creating smth like internet shop, I need make convert price at another currencies. For that i have service class

```
@product_decorator = Product.includes(:category).map{|product| ProductDecorator.new(product)}
```

Also i has table in db with actual courses

```
create_table :product_wrappers do |t|
      t.decimal :euro
      t.decimal :rubles
    end
```

In view it works good if i manually change product's price method at euro/rubles, but i need do it at link_to methods with new params like eur/rub, I'm rly stuck at that i need  create method in store_controller

Routes

```
  put '/set_currency', to: 'store#set_currency'
```

View

```
    <%= link_to "USD", set_currency_path(:currency => :usd), class: "btn btn-outline-secondary" %>

    <%= link_to "RUB", set_currency_path(:currency => :rub) ,class: "btn btn-outline-secondary" %>

    <%= link_to "EUR", set_currency_path(:currency => :eur), class: "btn btn-outline-secondary" %>
```

Comment: I am not sure you need few columns for different currencies in the database. May be you need some `settings` table where update currency rates

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want to show different prices on the pages like `/products/1?currency=eur` and `/products/1?currency=rub`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as ideas

To build URL with currency as query param use such helper

```
<%= link_to "My product", product_path(product, currency: :eur) %>
```

It will generate such HTML

```
<a href="/products/1?currency=eur">My product</a>
```

In your controller, probably `ApplicationController`

```
before_action :set_current_currency

def set_current_currency
  @current_currency = params[:currency] || 'eur'
end
```

And to show price in selected currency in views something like this

```
product.public_send(@current_currency)
```

Also may be it's a good idea to save selected currency in session or use user profile

```
def set_current_currency
  currency =
    if params[:currency]
      params[:currency]
    elsif session[:currency]
      session[:currency]
    elsif current_user
      current_user.preferred_currency
    end
    
  session[:currency] =
    if currencies.include?(currency)
      currency
    else
      default_currency
    end
end
```

And than use `session[:currency]` in your views instead of `@current_currency`